# What's the best format for QR Code file (SVG, JPG, TIFF, PNG)?

Tags: file, svg, jpeg

I'm trying to find out what is the best format type for `QR Code` file. What do you think about it? SVG always fine and scalable, but jpg has the smallest size. What do you think?

I want to find happy medium between quality and size.

Comment: Best format in what platform?

Comment: Do you mean language (Python, Java, C++)?

Comment: I thought more in web/mobile/desktop, but more details you fill in, higher chance someone can give you proper (with less guessing) answer.

Comment: It'll be WebApp (Client-Server). BackEnd on Java. FrontEnd on HTML+CSS+JS.

Comment: Are you sure jpg has the smallest size for QR codes? I would bet that the highly-repeated black-white pattern compresses best with PNG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with PNG (2nd place goes for JPEG). Reasons why not other formats:

- SVG - nice scaling, but if user wants to reuse image it might cause issues
- JPEG - no transparency (can't do creative stuff), artefacts if not using highest quality
- GIF - just let that format die
- TIFF - bad browser support
- PNG - best quality always, portable, transparency

Comment: What does mean _reuse_? To save file and change it?

Comment: For example email image itself. I'm not sure how many email clients (including mobile ones) support SVGs.

Answer (score 7):

TIFF is not supported by most web browsers, that leaves us with the remaining four formats.

Let's compare the sizes of this QR code (link to this page, saved with Gimp):

[image: qr code]

- JPEG, 90%: 39.4 kB
- JPEG, 50%: 25,7 kB
- PNG: 870 Bytes
- GIF: 6,8 kB
- SVG: 29 kB
- SVG, gzipped: 2,4 kB

Conclusion: JPEG is not only uglier, but also much larger than the other formats. GIF good, but **PNG is the smallest and has no downsides**. gzipped svg is just a little bigger, so if need it scalable, use SVG.